# NodeJS + redis gives weird results

Tags: node.js, node-redis

Maybe the results ain't weird, but I started using Node 1-2 months ago so for me they are...

I have a loop which sorts out every other value of the array returned by `hgetall` (Redis command) and in that loop I call a function to get all values from another table with keys stored in the sorted array. This was more difficult to explain than I thought. Here's my code:

Pastebin: http://pastebin.com/tAVhSUV1 (or see below)

```
function getInfo (cn, callback) {
        var anArray = [];
        redis_client.hgetall('chat_info:' + cn, function (err, vals) {
                if(err) { throw err; }
                for(i in vals) {
                        anArray.push(vals[i]);
                }
                return callback(anArray);
        });
}

redis_client.hgetall('chat_rooms:' + POST.chat_name, function (err, val) {
        if(err) { throw err; }
        var     vars = [],
                rArr = [];

        for (i in val) {
                vars.push(i);
        }
        for(var i = 0; i < vars.length; i += 1) {
                if(i%2 === 0) {
                        getInfo(vars[i], function (hej) {
                                rArr.push(hej);
                        });
                }
        }      
});
```

The callback from the call to `getInfo()` is executed after the entire loop. Am I missing out on something here? Because it can't do that, right? (when I use rArr (right after the loop) it's empty, nbBut if I log it in the callback it gets logged after everything else written *after* the loop)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's probably normal.

Understand that callbacks are executed after the `hgetall` call. Which mean that when the redis functions receive somehting it will call the callbacks. In other words, all the callbacks can be executed later.

As javascript only works in one thread, the calls to `hgetall` should be blocking to be executed as they come in the for loop. But as you're more certainly using async IO. The for loop ends and then it will start calling each callbacks that were queued inside the javascript event loop.

**Edit**

Unfortunately, to achieve what you're trying to do, you should wrap your code inside many other callbacks. You can use this project to make it easier: https://github.com/caolan/async

You should be able to install it using `npm install async`.

You'd have to do something like that:

```
function getInfo (cn) {
        return function(callback) {
            var anArray = [];
            redis_client.hgetall('chat_info:' + cn, function (err, vals) {
                if(err) { throw err; }
                for(i in vals) {
                        anArray.push(vals[i]);
                }
                return callback(anArray);
            });
        };
}

redis_client.hgetall('chat_rooms:' + POST.chat_name, function (err, val) {
        if(err) { throw err; }
        var     vars = [],
                rArr = [],
                callbacks = [];

        for (i in val) {
                vars.push(i);
        }

        for(var i = 0; i < vars.length; i += 1) {
                if(i%2 === 0) {
                        callbacks.push(getInfo(vars[i]));
                }
        }

        async.series(callbacks, function (err, results) {
           // Final code here
        });
});
```

Comment: What can I do to make the hgetall blocking then? Don't think redis support synchronous calling, and I can't figure out how to rewrite it to work the way I want it to.

Comment: Don't make it synchronous, it will block the server for every other requests. Instead use something like asyncjs.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, gave me some insight in this matter. I think I'll sit down with a pen and some paper and just rethink all of it.

Comment: Well, don't worry, if it's not too late, you could give python with gevent/gunicorn a try. Use one of the framework available and you should be able to write code without callbacks using async/io which should result in as good performance as node. Also don't worry for the callback's  mess, you're not the one who published something with bad design.